# Add a number of objects into an array n number of times in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I want to put copies of objects into an array *n* number of times, where *n* is a property of each of those objects that tells you how many times it needs to be copied in.

So I imagine I should do a loop, and for each object, look at it's property and loop the loop that integer's number of times.

```
var myArray = {};
var object1 = {
    "copyMeThisManyTimes": 4,
    "name": "Sam"
}
var object2 = {
    "copyMeThisManyTimes": 2,
    "name": "Max"
}
for (i=0; i < this.copyMeThisManyTimes; i++) {
    myArray.push(this);
}
```

Maybe that `for` loop should be in an $each or something so there is a scope that "this" is based on?

**Back story:** Some creature objects are more rare than others in this game I am coding.  I want to create a "deck" of enemy cards.  Certain enemies should come up more often than others - consider them "common".  Each object has a rarity property - this integer will determine the number of times duplicates of this object will be placed into the array to ensure common ones are seen more frequently.  I figure this will be a good way to do rarity, but I'm totally open to other options via Javascript or jQuery (prefer vanilla js).

Another option a friend mentioned would be to have a separate array for each "rarity" category, and pick a random number for enemy selection, and more of those numbers would point to the "common" array and fewer to the "rare" array.  For example a dice roll of 1-4 would pick an enemy from the "common" array.  What's the best way to do this?

I'm sure there is an embarrassingly easier way, so I apologize in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing really wrong with your logic. Just a bit of implementation issues.

```js
var myArray = []; // array literal, not object
var object1 = {
    "copyMeThisManyTimes": 4, // was missing a quote
    "name": "Sam"
}
var object2 = {
    "copyMeThisManyTimes": 2, // also
    "name": "Max"
}
for (i=0; i < object1.copyMeThisManyTimes; i++) { // can't use this, need to specify an object
    myArray.push(object1.name); // push the value you want
}
for (i=0; i < object2.copyMeThisManyTimes; i++) { // again for the second object
    myArray.push(object2.name);
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

If you have lots of objects, it might be better to place them in an array, and loop over that.

```js
var myArray = [];
var arrayOfObjects = [{
    "copyMeThisManyTimes": 4,
    "name": "Sam"
}, {
    "copyMeThisManyTimes": 2, // also
    "name": "Max"
}];
for (i=0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < arrayOfObjects[i].copyMeThisManyTimes; j++) {
        myArray.push(arrayOfObjects[i].name);
    }
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I'm looking over it.  Thank you for responding so quickly after I posted it!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid objects duplication, you could have 2 arrays:

- one containing an instance of each kind of object
- the other containing the indexes of the object to be selected according to the
  dice roll

For exemple if the first item of the object array is the common one, the 4 first values in the second array would be 0, so a dice roll of 1-4 would pick a common enemy.

Only indexes would be duplicated, not objects.

```
var enemies = [
    {
        name: "max"
    },
    {
        name: "sam"
    }
]
// a dice roll of 1-4 will return "max", a dice roll of 5-6 will return "sam"
var rarity = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1];
selectedIndex = rarity[Math.floor(Math.random() * rarity.length)];
selectedEnemy = enemies[selectedIndex];
```